# Playwright annotations expect 2 arguments but got 3

Tags: javascript, annotations, playwright

I have been writing tests in playwright without issue and as the number of tests is starting to increase I would like to add tags to help manage them, I would like to add the tag as an argument rather than including them in the title as this seems a lot neater especially in the html reporter.

When I try to add a tag as an argument, I get an error saying that the test() function 'expects 2 arguments but got 3'. I've looked over the playwright documents to find if there's anything I've missed but even Playwright's example code throws the same error.
[screenshot of the example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tZg0.png)

Here is a link to playwright's docs
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations

Comment: Please convert your screenshot of code to text. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for rationale. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Playwright installation to version 1.42